# Developing and testing static web pages in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, iis, web

I'm trying to develop a static HTML + JavaScript web site using Visual Studio 2012 and, oh boy, am I having trouble getting the simplest things to work.

I have been using the following Visual Studio template on Visual Studio 2012: https://purehtml.codeplex.com/ (it mystifies me that there isn't such a thing available by default).

I have added a *js* folder to the project in preference to the default *lib*.

I have edited the default *index.html* file and set it as the start-up page.

When I hit Ctrl+F5 to test the page, my web browser (Chrome) starts up and shows some unhelpful error gobbledygook.  For example, trying *use local IIS web server* in the project settings, I get a web page starting thus:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070003
Config Error       Cannot read configuration file
Config File    \\?\C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Rawb\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:36263/rawb/
Physical Path      C:\Users\Ralph\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Rawb\
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\Ralph\SkyDrive\My Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\RAWB-SITE
```

If I spoke ancient Mayan that might be helpful.

*All that needs to happen* is for the files and folders of my project to be copied *somewhere* (where?!) so the web server can serve them.  Why is this so blooming difficult to arrange?!

I have tried every combination of project settings I can think of, I have spent hours googling for the right mystic incantations, and have had no luck at all.  I don't care whether I use local IIS or the VS Development Server.

Can some kind soul please explain to me, in words of one syllable, suitable for a slow child, exactly what I have to do to be able to hit F5 in Visual Studio and see the fruits of my labour presented in a web browser?  [Seriously, if you could mention every click, I would be eternally grateful: most "explanations" on the web assume some secret knowledge that isn't written in one place shorter than the Bible.]

Comment: Can you just create a blank solution then add your html files and your js files? Then just right click on your html file, then view in browser

Comment: The error sounds like VS is trying to use the IIS on your computer and the IIS is not installed. See if all is well with the IIS. Otherwise, if I create a new website : ASP.NET Empty Website, and then add a html file and set it as startup page, I can just run with Ctrl+F5 to show it in the browser. If you do the same, without externally downloaded templates or Javascript files, does it work?

Comment: PS if you are serious about developing websites, I am afraid you _will_ have to learn ancient Mayan (that is, the terminology used in the error message).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, eggward and @Mr Lister: much appreciated.  What I've ended up doing (this will probably make those in the know wince) is this: mklinking from inetpub/wwwroot to my project directory and granting IUSR read access to that directory tree.  I was rather hoping that IIS/Visual Studio would provide some simple, elegant mechanism for this which I could understand in its entirety.  As it is, IIS/VS seem to do a lot of magic behind the scenes which few understand, judging by the number of magic recipes I've found on the web while searching for a solution.

Comment: @Mr Lister... IIS ( probably IISExpress) is processing the request as "IIS Web Core" module responded.  

I noticed that the path to the web.config file is in your AppData/Local/Temporary Projects folder.  Have you saved the project as I don't think the IUSR_*** accounts have rights to read that folder... hence the error about configuration data being invalid